# How to restart a code included into a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to restart my python code from the beginning after a given "yes" input from the user, but I can't understand what I'm doing wrong here:

```
if input("Other questions? ") == 'yes' or 'yeah':
    main()
else:
    pass
```

my code is included within the function main().
Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Can you elaborate on what is going wrong?

Comment: To whoever closed this question, the question/answer you linked to appears totally unrelated to this question?

Comment: @kamion No, `input("Other questions? ") == 'yes' or 'yeah'` is the problem, and the question linked explains how to fix it.

(Note: I didn't close the question)

Answer (score 2):

You would probably do it with a while loop around the whole thing you want repeated, and as Loic RW said in the comments, just break out of the while loop:

```
while True:
    # do whatever you want

    # at the end, you ask your question:
    if input("Other questions? ") in ['yes','yeah']:
        # this will loop around again
        pass
    else:
        # this will break out of the while loop
        break
```

Comment: `if` statement will be true no matter whatever you pass

Comment: You could also write `while True:` and then under `else` write `break`

Comment: Ooops. I just copied and paste the original code and didn't look at it closely. My bad. Edited the if condition. Thanks @RustamGarayev

Comment: thanks for the help, I'll have a look

Comment: @LoicRW, yes that's also do-able.